# function in directive's scope unwanted fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm passing a function to a directive by the attribute.

**The problem** is that the function fired before I call it. The more strange issue is that this is happen only when I declare a directive's scope.

If it's not clear, my code will explain:

**Without defined scope**

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.testString = 'test string';
  $scope.testFunction = function(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
}).directive('test', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <span test="testFunction(testString)">Test Directive</span>
</div>
```

**With defined scope**

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.testString = 'test string';
  $scope.testFunction = function(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
}).directive('test', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      test: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <span test="testFunction(testString)">Test Directive</span>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/hunewu/edit?html,js

**Another point** In the case of defined directive's scope, why the function fired 3 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be passing expression binding(function reference) to directive using `=`(two way binding). Ideally it should be using `&`(expression binding) while dealing with such cases.

**Directive**

```
.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      test: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      //then call whenever you want it
      scope.test({testString: 'myOwnString'});
    }
  };
});
```

[**CodePen**](http://jsbin.com/sivisubuce/1/edit?html,js,output)